# Changing the dafault output format

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to change the default evaluation output to "numerical value"? I think I've done this before by putting some code in a init.m file but can't remember anymore

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation for $Post

```
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html
```

which should do what you are looking for

Comment: Like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/278139/363) even with just `form[x_Real] := DecimalForm[x, 16];` suitable for most purposes.